# App Center Issue in Gnome Desktop after KDE Plasma Desktop Installation (not Kubuntu)

Tags: kde, app-center

I have reviewed the guidelines for bug submission, but I am uncertain about the package that the App Center belongs to. Is it part of a snap package? If so, could you please provide further details?

I recently installed the kde-plasma-desktop to have the option of running KDE alongside GNOME. However, upon logging back into GNOME, I noticed that the App Center icon in the dock had changed to a square with an exclamation point. Additionally, it now takes approximately 60 seconds to load when clicked.

I would greatly appreciate any assistance you can provide in resolving this issue. Thank you in advance for your help!